# Pad dates within groups with pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to pad dates within a group ('type') and backfill the new rows. I've seen examples using reindex, but I'm not sure how to pad these dates while maintaining the groups.

in:

```
type    date        value
a       2016-01-01  1
a       2016-01-04  3
b       2016-01-10  4
b       2016-01-13  7
```

desired out:

```
type    date        value
a       2016-01-01  1
a       2016-01-02  3
a       2016-01-03  3
a       2016-01-04  3
b       2016-01-10  4
b       2016-01-11  7
b       2016-01-12  7
b       2016-01-13  7
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
df.set_index('date').groupby('type', as_index=False).resample('d').bfill().reset_index().drop('level_0', axis=1)
Out: 
        date type  value
0 2016-01-01    a      1
1 2016-01-02    a      3
2 2016-01-03    a      3
3 2016-01-04    a      3
4 2016-01-10    b      4
5 2016-01-11    b      7
6 2016-01-12    b      7
7 2016-01-13    b      7
```

Comment: Thanks! So this turns the date column into an index? Is it possible to keep it as a column?

Comment: You can add one more `.reset_index()` at the end.

Comment: I posted another alternative as well.

Comment: Great, that works. However, it also seems to drop any non-numerical columns?

Comment: It preserves the non-numerical columns when I try it (backfills them as well). Which one are you trying?

Comment: I'm trying the latest solution you provided.

Comment: Can it be a version issue? With pandas 0.18.1 I have this: http://imgur.com/a/lEol3